# How do I periodically purge a queue in celery rabbitmq?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

How can I periodically purge celery queues, like per minute after there are any unfinished task left in queue then I need to purge all those task after a minute.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to timeout tasks, use [Time to Live](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html); otherwise purging the queue if there's an old task could case a new task to be discarded with it.

You can set it with

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy TTL ".*" '{"message-ttl":60000}' --apply-to queues
```

and your queue will now discard tasks older than 1 minute.

That said, there is a `purge` command in RMQ that you can just call on a timer.
https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/current/com/rabbitmq/client/AMQP.Queue.html

Comment: but i don't want all my queues to be cleared , only selected queues need to be cleared , that includes tickers , etc

Answer (score 1):

You can set `time_limit` for the task to kill it after a certain amount of time.
[Celery Time Limits](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits)

```
@app.task(time_limit=60)
def long_running_task():
    ...
```

Comment: Hi I added  to the queue like this @celery_app_cron.task(time_limit=60,queue='ticker_queue')   but nothing is happening

Comment: Does your task still execute after 60 seconds time limit?

Comment: Yeah it is executing , after 60 seconds , all the pending queues are not cleared even after 60 seconds so task keeps on accumulating after evertime cron is run

Comment: And also this is not what i want this kill the task that is currently executing the task greater than the time then it will kill that task , what i need is any task that is pending in the queue should be removed